# C# Calling Powershell script fails

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I have a strange situation with calling a PS-script from a C# application:
I created a simple application which should retrieve the state of virtual machines ( running, stopped, deallocated) from the Azure environment. Therefore I tried several thing and the most simple one is executing a PowerShell script, gets the states of the VM's and use it in my application so I can do something with this information. Before running the PS-script, I do a find-replace so C# parses the username and password to login at Azure so it's not stored in my ps1-file.

When I try this method on my development machine (Win10 and VS2017 community), it all runs fine ( C# calling PowerShell and gets the output). The script is executed and I am able to use the information as desired. But, when I try this on a server (Win2012) it tells me the Login-Azurermaccount and get-azurermvm are not recognised as the name of a cmdlet. When I try to run the exact same script from the command line by running powershell -file 'filename.ps1', it runs as it should?

Does anyone have an explanation for this of maybe the same problems?

On dev.machine and server are the same versions of PS:5.1

Comment: Could you please post a small example / C# code snippet which doesn't run as you wish on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Success on your Win10 Dev box, indicates you have the Azure module installed / loaded and you re already logged into Azure.

The Azure module must be installed / loaded on a host (directly or proxied) and you must be logged into Azure to use them and access Azure data.

Answer (score 0):

Running it on your local machine against your own profile and finding it might indicate the module is auto loaded when you run.  Try the PowerShell.exe on the local with -noprofile and you might get a different result (the error like on the server).

As far as making it work in both environments, I'd recommend you put code in the script to explicitly add the module you need (assuming you installed the SDK on the server).

Add this at the top of the module as the first line.  Confirm the file exists on both machines before you do, to indicate that it has been installed the same way.

Import-Module "c:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\AzureRM.psd1"

If it's not installed on the server, here's installation instructions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/other-install?view=azurermps-5.1.1